# Force where in ActiveRecord model in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause, default-scope

Is there any way to force a where statement to be included in every SELECT-statement I do with Active Record? I'm using Rails 4.

For example:
If I call:

```
Product.where(name: 'Fishing rod')
```

Then I want Rails to generate a SQL query like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE products.client_id = 1 AND (name = 'Fishing rod')
```

where `products.client_id = 1` is the forced where statement. All other *conditions* I define via where or other ORM-methods (like `find` or whatever) should be included in the statement aswell.

Is there a possibility to define such *forced condition*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`default_scope`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/default_scope)

In your model

```
default_scope { where(client_id: 1) }
```

According to the docs

> The default_scope is also applied while creating/building a record. It
>   is not applied while updating a record.

because of this I would recommend that you use a more explicit method and define a named scope like this

```
scope :client_one, -> { where(client_id: 1) }
```

which you would use like this then

```
Product.client_one.where(...)
```

Comment: Thanks alot, `default_scope` was exactly what I was looking for. Setting `client_id` when creating and initializing is not a disadvantage, it saves me some code as I first wanted to do this by adding `after_save` filters.